# Does the Qt MQTT package provide an easy way of writing my own broker?

Tags: qt, mqtt

I'm considering trying the MQTT implementation provided by Qt.
I've studied the documentation, the classes, the members of the classes, and the examples. Nowhere did I find anything indicating how to make my own broker.
All the examples, and all the classes and the available source code seem to be limited to creating a client. The examples use some online broker service to test this client.

So, does the Qt MQTT package provide an easy way of writing my own broker?

Comment: Qt MQTT is made to write clients

Comment: @eyllanesc : it's not explicitly stated so, I only assumed it from the lack of any code handling it. Still, "No" is a perfectly valid answer if it's correctly referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is for clients. The overview pretty much says so

> It enables applications to act as telemetry displays and devices to publish telemetry data.